# Looping through Rows, Cloumns, and Intersection VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I want to loop through a spreadsheet and gather the Header, the Row Header, and the Value in the cell where those two intersect. Then build an array of these values.

This is the example

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 
C1  1     1  2
C2     3     
C3  2        4
C4  1     1
```

And the final output of the array would be something like

```
V1, C1, 1
V2, C1, 0
V3, C1, 1
V4, C1, 4
V1, C2, 0
V2, C2, 3
etc
```

I will then sort through this array and eliminate any entries that have a "0" value.

Problem: I am not the best in practice with this and keep receiving errors when trying to define variables or array entries. I feel like the idea is sound, but syntax wise, I cannot get past specific errors.

I suppose I wouldn't want someone to solve it entirely becauyse that defeats the learning purpose

My initial solution was to build an array or the Header, an array of the Row header, and an array of the data.

Basically an array of the V values, Another of the C values, and one of the integer values.

I wrote the code below (again please forgive my ignorance).

As far as I know, it should Loop through the first range grabbing value V1 (or C2 in my code) the loop through 2nd range grabbing value C1 (or A2 in my code) then The value of 1 (I'll call it Z1). Then increase the integer as to grab V2, then C1, Then Z2 and so on.

```
Dim myarrayX() As Variant
Dim myarrayY() As Variant
Dim myarrayZ() As Variant
Dim myarrayHeader() As Variant
Dim myarrayRowHeader() As Variant
Dim myarrayIntersection() As Variant
Dim Result() As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Variant
Dim k As Variant
Dim l As Variant
Dim m As Variant
Dim n As Variant


l = 0
m = 0
n = 0



myarrayHeader = Range("C2:H2").Value
myarrayRowHeader = Range("A2:A6").Value
myarrayIntersection = Range("C2:H6").Value



For Each i In myarrrayHeader.Cells
    myarrayX(l) = Cell.Value
        For Each j In myarrayRowHeader.Cells
            myarrayY(m) = Cell.Value
                For Each k In myarrayIntersection.Cells
                    myarrayZ(n) = Cell.Value

                    k = k + 1
                    i = i + 1
                    n = n + 1
                 Next k
             m = m + 1
       Next j
       l = l + 1
       j = j + 1
Next i
```

I cannot get any output as it says "invalid qualifier" for "myarrayRowHeader.Cells" and I cannot figure out why that is.

Comment: Remove `.Value` from `myarrayRowHeader = Range("A2:A6").Value`

Comment: @AAA - your suggestion won't work by itself - consider what the _default property is!

Comment: @AJD, the OP's last question was about the invalid qualifier they were getting. The `.Value` property doesn't necessarily return a range. I wasn't posting a full answer to the question, as the OP says they want to work on it themselves. I was only helping to figure a question they asked. And the answer could be much simpler than what you put below.

Comment: @AAA but just dropping the `.Value` does not change the result in your suggestion, because of the default properties on ranges, it will still return an array of values! Not only does the `Set` keyword have to change, but also the declarations.

Comment: The point is, the code wouldn't work anyway which is why my answer is more complicated.

Comment: Or you could first get the values of respective cells, concatenate them to build up another range and then convert the answer to an array. If your answer works, fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot get any output as it says "invalid qualifier" for
>   "myarrayRowHeader.Cells" and I cannot figure out why that is.

You have two problems here. The first and obvious one is a typo. Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of the modules. ***Always***.

You have declared the following as Variants, with the intent of filling them with values - making them arrays of values:

```
Dim myarrayHeader() As Variant '<-- Actually, this is an array of Variants, also not what you want!
Dim myarrayRowHeader() As Variant
Dim myarrayIntersection() As Variant
```

Indeed - you do fill these arrays with values at the beginning of your code.

```
myarrayHeader = Range("C2:H2").Value ' One row, multiple columns
myarrayRowHeader = Range("A2:A6").Value ' Multiple rows, one column
myarrayIntersection = Range("C2:H6").Value ' Multiple rows, multiple columns
```

At this point, they are arrays, not objects, so do not have any intrinsic methods or properties. In other words for `myarrayRowHeader` there is no `.Cells` method or property, hence the VBA compiler is complaining.

The correct syntax for your code is to simple loop through the arrays:

```
For i = LBound(myarrrayHeader, 2) to UBound(myarrrayHeader, 2) ' <--- typo here 
    myarrayX(l) = myarrayHeader(I,1)
        For j = LBound(myarrayRowHeader, 1) to UBound(myarrayRowHeader, 1)
            myarrayY(m) = myarrayRowHeader(j,1)
'etc.
```

Note that when converting an Excel Range to an array, it is always a 2-D array, even if only one column is selected.

But because you are working in multiple columns and arrays, your simple loops won't work. You must understand the relative relationships in space, like below.

```
Dim myarrayHeader As Variant 
Dim myarrayRowHeader As Variant
Dim myarrayIntersection As Variant
dim myarray(,) as Variant
myarrayHeader = Range("C2:H2").Value ' One row, multiple columns
myarrayRowHeader = Range("A2:A6").Value ' Multiple rows, one column
myarrayIntersection = Range("C2:H6").Value ' Multiple rows, multiple columns

Dim rowNum as Long
rowNum = 1

ReDim myarray(UBound(myarrayRowHeader,1) * UBound(myarrayHeader, 2),3) ' <--- double check this for right numbers

For i = LBound(myarrayHeader, 2) to UBound(myarrayHeader, 2) 
    For j = LBound(myarrayRowHeader, 1) to UBound(myarrayRowHeader, 1)
        myarray(rowNum, 1) = myarrayHeader(1,i)
        myarray(rowNum, 2) = myarrayRowHeader(j,1)
        myarray(rowNum, 3) = myarrayIntersection(I,j)
        rowNum = rowNum+1
    Next j
Next I
```

Edit:

My original code just considered resizing the final array based on a single dimension, but the final array is, of course, based on both dimensions. This caused an out of bounds error in the original code as the OP tried to traverse all the data.

The other option, to keep things in UBound(x,1) mode is to use `.Transpose`:

```
myarrayHeader = Range("C2:H2").Transpose.Value ' Now multiple rows, one column
```

Comment: Just for my own sake of understanding.

The redim statement is redefining "myarray" with the bound of how long the "myarrayRowHeader" column extends and 3 entries to allow the three values obtained in the second nested for statement?

I am receiving a subscript out of range unless I change the value of the "for i" statement from  "LBound(myarrayHeader, 2) to UBound(myarrayHeader, 2) " to "LBound(myarrayHeader, 1) to UBound(myarrayHeader, 1)"

Comment: yes, the `ReDim` sets up the array you want in the end. Does it work the way you want when you redefine the UBound?

Comment: Yes the values are correct after a small adjustment, thank you very much.

Comment: @Danny, fixed up my coding error that caused your out of range error. The reason changing it to UBound(myarrayHeader, 1) seemed to work is that the first dimension size is "1", thus matching the other dimension. However, you would not have got all your data (`For I = 1 To 1`). Check out http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx for some good reading on this.